# In a Try block, is it better to create one Catch for multiple exceptions OR one Catch for each exception?

Tags: java, exception

I am curious which one is more practical, and which cases do we need to use the first and where we need to use the second?  For example in Java7:

first.java

```
try {
  /* some code that throws these exceptions */
} catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException e) {
    throw new MyAPIException("Something went wrong", e);
} catch (FactoryException e) {
    throw new MyAPIException("Something went wrong", e);
} catch (MismatchedDimensionException e) {
    throw new MyAPIException("Something went wrong", e);
} catch (TransformException e) {
    throw new MyAPIException("Something went wrong", e);
}
```

second.java

```
try {
  /* some code that throws these exceptions */
} catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException | FactoryException| MismatchedDimensionException | TransformException e) {
    /*handle all exceptions*/;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle each error. Do you want the same thing to occur with each error, or do you need a specific error for each error?

Comment: @Mena They can all be named `e`, that's not a problem in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to handle each exception differently?  If yes, have different catch blocks with different behaviors.  If you want to handle all the exceptions in the same way, one catch block is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly answered by TangledUpInBlue, If only you need to handle it differently and want different actions on different types of actions, use individual catches.

Otherwise use the parent class `Exception`, one for all:

```
try{

}
catch(Exception e){

}
```